# Bind HashSet to a ListView Item (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged, hashset

I'm trying to bind a HashSet to a ListView item. I've documented my code here:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressList = new AddressList ();
}
public class AddressList : HashSet<Addresses>
{
    //
}
public class Addresses {
    public string Streetname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private Person _person;

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        _person= person; 
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _person.Name; }
        set
        {
            _person.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}

 // This is how I add the DataContext: mainGrid.DataContext = _person //this is a PersonViewModel();
 // This is how I bind the DataObjects to the GUI Elements: <TextBox Name="TxtBoxName" Text="{Binding Path=.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
 // How can I add in the same way a HashSet to a ListView Element in the WPF Gui? I tried something like {Binding Path=.Name, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Can anyone help me with tipps how to accomplish that? Thanks a lot!

Cheers

Comment: Also unless you're adding (or needing) an IEqualityComparer for your Addresses class, I would avoid using HashSet instead of a simpler collection, say List<T>.

Comment: But wouldn't HashSet be faster? I actually don't need any specific HashSet function (except for the "nice-to-have" unique entries part)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a collection to a `ListView` (or any `ItemsControl`, for that matter), you need to set its `ItemsSource` property. This should be bound to an instance of your `AddressList` class, assuming that collection is what you want displayed in your list.

Once you've done that, you'll need to set up the bindings for each column in the `ListView`, similar to how your comment at the bottom of the sample code describes it.

Answer (score 0):

[<strike>This example</strike>](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=20) binds to an XML data source, but you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

See also the MSDN documentation for ListView [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972.aspx).